# removing tailing and leading strings from variable in one step

Tags: bash

I have a string in the var f that is "res/some/path/file.ext.patch" and I want to remove the ".patch" and the "res/".
That means I expect the result to be "some/path/file.ext".

I know that I can remove the leading "res/" with `${f#res/}` and the tailing ".patch" with `${f%.patch}`

I want to replace both in one step without using a temp variable so I tried this:
`${${f#res/}%.patch}` but I get the following error:

`/bin/bash: ${${f#res/}%.patch}: Wrong variable substitution.`

What

Comment: You can't chain operators like this. Only a *name* is allowed before the `%`, not an arbitrary value.

Comment: `$(echo $file | sed 's#^res/\(.*\)\.patch$#\1#')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter expansion operators cannot be chained. The closest you can come to doing this in one step is to use a regular expression match.

```
[[ $f =~ res/(.*).patch ]] && f=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

I leave it up to you if that is preferable to

```
f=${f#res/}
f=${f%.patch}
```